# Java: incompatible return type with a class implementing an interface

Tags: java, interface

I have an interface and an implementation:

```
// there are things
public interface Thing { /* ... */ }
```

```
// balls are things
public class Ball implements Thing { /* ... */ }
```

I have another interface and another implementation:

```
// a dog can fetch any thing
public interface Dog {
    public Thing fetch();
}
```

```
// a shepherd can fetch only a ball
public class Shepherd implement Dog {
    public Ball fetch() { /* ... */ }
}
```

This is fine.

But now I want to use `Ball` as a parameter of a parametrized class:

```
public interface Dog {
    public List<Thing> fetchList();
}
```

```
public class Shepherd implement Dog {
    public List<Ball> fetchList() { /* ... */ }
}
```

Java doesn't allow me to do so, it says I'm attempting to use incompatible type.

At the same time this construction works without any issues:

```
public class Shepherd implement Dog {
    public List<Thing> fetchList() { /* ... */ }
}
```

Why does Java allow me to use an implementation of an interface as the returning value's definition, but doesn't allow me to use it as the parametrized class' parameter?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because not every `Thing` is a `Ball`

Comment: In java generics, a `List<Ball>` is not a subclass of `List<Thing>` even though `Ball` extends `Thing`. That's why there is a construct like `List<? extends Thing>`. Have a look at [Generics, Inheritance and Subtypes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html) which is part of Oracle's java tutorials.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I should have read carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because not every `Thing` is a  is a `Ball`

You can try to parametrize super type like this

```
public interface Dog<T extends Thing> {
    public List<T> fetchList();
}

public class Shepherd implement Dog<Ball> {
    public List<Ball> fetchList() { /* ... */ }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! But... That's right, not every `Thing` is a `Ball`, but why there's an error in using `List<Ball> fetch()` and no error in using `Ball fetch()`?